# Unable to see my distribution group in Azure Graph Explorer

Tags: graph

Issue #1:
I am using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf to see all the DG I am member of and not showing 
complete list. Verified against IDWeb.

Issue #2: Able to login only in preview UI. In Ga, its keep asking Microsoft credentials